# Entity Framework Core generates a new column when selecting from the children tables from a View

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core

I have a table in my database **Customer** and have an external database table **Customer** with a lot of information, I created a **CustomerAccount** view for representing this

**View - CustomerAccount**

```
CREATE VIEW CustomerAccount AS
SELECT c.Id, c.CustomerNumber, a.Name, ISNULL(DateTimeCreated, 0) as CreatedDate, ISNULL(DateTimeUpdated, ISNULL(DateTimeCreated, 0)) as UpdatedDate, ~InactiveFlag as Active 
FROM externaldatabase..CMAccount a
INNER JOIN mydatabase..Customer c on a.URI = c.CustomerNumber;
```

**My table - Customer**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CustomerNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Active] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Customer] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

**Product1** and **Product2** tables have foreign keys for my database **Customer** table

**Configuration for the table Product1**

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Product1> builder)
{
    builder
        .HasKey(b => b.Id);

    // all other properties

    builder
        .HasOne(b => b.Customer)
        .WithMany();
}
```

**Configuration for the table Product2**

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Product2> builder)
{
    builder
        .HasKey(b => b.Id);

    // all other properties

    builder
        .HasOne(b => b.Customer)
        .WithMany();
}
```

**Configuration for the table Customer:**

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Customer> builder)
{
    builder
        .HasKey(b => b.Id);

    builder
        .HasIndex(b => b.CustomerNumber);

    builder
        .Property(b => b.CustomerNumber)
        .IsRequired();

    builder
        .Property(b => b.CreatedDate)
        .HasColumnType("datetime")
        .IsRequired();

    builder
        .Property(b => b.UpdatedDate)
        .HasColumnType("datetime")
        .IsRequired();

    builder
        .Property(b => b.Active)
        .IsRequired();
}
```

**Configuration for the view CustomerAccount:**

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<CustomerAccount> builder)
{
    builder
        .ToView(nameof(CustomerAccount));

    builder
        .HasMany(c => c.Product1Setups)
        .WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey(p1 => p1.CustomerId);

    builder
        .HasMany(c => c.Product2Setups)
        .WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey(p2 => p2.CustomerId);
}
```

Even if I use the string overload as below the same happens:

```
builder
    .HasMany(c => c.Product2Setups)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey("CustomerId");
```

I was expecting only a logical relationship between those, but when selecting from Product1 or Product2 EF core generates a query with an *invalid column name **CustomerId1***. Both tables are already a column named CustomerId referenced by mydatabase..Customer of the example above.

Is there any solution for that?

**UPDATE - TL/DR:**

In summary what I need to do is to have two parent objects, one table and one view being referenced by the same columns in the children tables, since the view shares the same unique key basically.

Comment: In your `Product` table you want to have two navigation properties (namely `Product1Setups` and `Product2Setups`) to the `CustomerTable`. Since they are different two foreign keys should be defined in the `CustomerTable`, so I guess the EF tries to do this for you and generate the name for the column.

Comment: Think about it from the database perspective, if you want the `product1` to appear in `customer1's Product1Setups` and in `customer2's Product2Setups` props, then you set the `CustomerId1` column of the product table to `customer1` and the `CustomerId2` column to `customer2`

Comment: Sorry @E.Shcherbo, I used the Product1 and Product2 table only to exemplify the two tables I have in my database, those are two different tables and are already referenced by the Customer table and it makes total sense if the CustomerAccount was a table, but this being a view I think there should be a way of referencing the same column even with two different parent objects

Comment: Oh, I apologize, I didn't notice they are different tables

Comment: You should show all parts of the class model involved here, including the navigation properties and FK properties. It's not clear where you have `CustomerId` and how the `Customer` class is involved.

Comment: Hey, @GertArnold, added all the other pieces in terms of EF core configuration

Comment: So both "Product" entities have FK to Customer and to CustormerAccount. That's two FKs per entity. I think you need a 1:1 between Customer and CustomerAccount.

Comment: Yes, basically, but I'd like to have the structure navigation like CustomerAccount>Product, in that way I will need to have CustomerAccount>Customer>Product

Comment: Could you please provide the definitions of your classes? I think I understand what's the problem (have an answer for it), but need to take a look at definitions to say properly